# Unity adding float to PlayerPrefs.SetFloat

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I am trying to add a value to playerprefs when I press a button, but cant quite figure it out. Here is what I have so far:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class Button21 : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void NextLevel() {
        Application.LoadLevel("Quiz2");
    }


    PlayerPrefs.setFloat("finalScore" + 1f);
}
```

So that is the second button, the first one on the previous scene sets "finalScore" to 1, 2, 3, or 4 depending on what button you press. I want this to set "finalScore" to 1, 2, 3, or 4 **+** 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined a class of "Button21" which is a subclass of MonoBehaviour. How do you intend on implementing "OnTouched" event (just example of possible name for a method)? You should use either OnGui() in some generic UI class and draw your button or you could just drag-drop some UI components and "hook'em up" to your class public method. To make your life easier, here is a snippet:

```
void OnGui () {
   if (GUI.Button(Rect(10,70,50,30),"Click"))
            Debug.Log("Clicked the button with text");
}
```

Read the docs here http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html

Next thing - you are using UserPrefs wrong. You want to call:

```
PlayerPrefs.setFloat("finalScore",1);
```

Then again this will set a key "finalScore" to value 1. You want to set it to your variable "finalScore" or so.

So in the end, the snippet could look like:

```
void OnGui () {
       if (GUI.Button(Rect(10,70,50,30),"Save Score"))
                PlayerPrefs.setFloat("finalScore",finalScore);
    }
```

And as i mentioned you can use GUI elements by adding them to scene and just calling your own public method by hooking them up in inspector.

EDIT #1

To simplify things for OP i will give another example:

```
public class ScoreCalculator : MonoBehaviour {

    public int[] finalScore = new int[8];

    public void IncreaseMyScore (int increaseAmount, int forLevel) {
      finalScore[forLevel] += increaseAmount;
    }

    public void IncreaseByOne (int forLevel) {
       IncreaseMyScore(1, forLevel);
    }

    public void SaveMyScores () {
       for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
          PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("FinalScore"+i,finalScore[i]);
    }
}
```

Just call method "IncreaseByOne" from your button.

This will save all your scores like this: FInalScore0, FinalScore1, etc.

NOTE: There are much more efficient ways to save an array, please read unity docs and PlayerPrefs documentation too. I just sketched a fast solution for ya.

EDIT #3:
Points to upgrade:
 Use list with dictionaries and level names/score to store your score. This way you will not be limited to level index and expanding amount of levels.

Save/Load whole lists/arrays by using PlayerPrefsX: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ArrayPrefs2.

Separate logic so that only one component would be responsible for score loading/saving and handling.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a way to continue to add values. This is going into a quiz, and the end result is determined on how many points they have. I am using different scenes for each question so I need a way to store the points though all the scenes while adding them up when they click a button.

Comment: You can do this simply by setting your finalScore as a global public integer and then saving it whenever needed. Taken that this script that holds your parameter will not be destroyed on next scene load.

Comment: I have a different script for each button, with 4 buttons in a scene and 8 scenes total.

Comment: You do not need that really. You could suffice with one class that simply increases your score and saves it if needed. NOTE: use playerPrefs for SAVING values not for having some global variables in this case.

Comment: the button also takes you to the next scene, but I see what you are saying. So, I would create a new script saving the score? But each button needs to save a different score, like button 1 saves a score of 1, button 2 a score of 2 and so on.

Comment: Alright, so I would just add "IncreaseByTwo" and things like that?

Comment: Well i edited my answer. You can just use one method and provide it with amount of score and number of your level. You will have to figure out loading of scores yourself (not hard at all). And saving right here is very optional i just made it to show how PlayerPrefs could be used.

Comment: I have a few errors now, one being "setFloat" does not have a description, the other being "finalScore" is not defined.

Comment: Issues should be gone now. "setFloat" does not exist - "SetFloat" does. And every array must be initialized. Those weren't hard to see.

Comment: @NuckG, just to follow up from your other question, the proper syntax is `public int[] finalScore = new int[8];` not what the person wrote in the answer.

Comment: @avuthless I edited your answer to remove the syntax error in the declaration, feel free to roll back if you feel you need to.

Comment: Thanks for catching that!